# react-doc-viewer > view.officeapps.live.com is it free or paid for accessible

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

react-doc-viewer full preview is paid or not

I have one problem is this link is paid or free for development? `view.officeapps.live.com`

I am using the react-doc-viewer>
in that we have button for full screen preview >
when i click on that it redirecting to https://view.officeapps.live.com with file URL.
I just have question that URL is free or paid?